# Parsing csv data: TextFieldParser vs Split

Tags: .net, text, csv, split

VB2005. So just diong some testing and ran into this oddity while parsing my CSV data with the TextFieldParser http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/679596/textfieldparser-does-not-respect-consecutive-line-breaks-in-the-middle-of-a-field where it doesn't recognize repeated line breaks in a field. Note that this is not the same as skipping blank fields. Anyway, I am testing an alternative way to get the data. I am trying the plain old Split function but that function cant handle embedded commas in a field like the TextFieldParser can. Are there any workarounds to this issue?

As an example the source data field reads:

```
"this is line 1
this is line 2

this is line 3


this is line 4
this is line 5"
```

And after I parse it with the TextFieldParser I get an output:

```
this is line 1
this is line 2
this is line 3
this is line 4
this is line 5
```

Seemingly any blank line gets ignored. If I had a memo with several paragraphs in the field this would jumble it all together with no spacing between. Does any else see this behavior?

Update: Used the CSV reader from Code project http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader and it works great. Doesn't trim the inner line breaks on empty lines.

Comment: Does the data have multiple line breaks in a fields and do you need multiple line breaks in fields?

Comment: Well yes and no. The application is for reading and converting the users data. If the user has a field that has multiple line feeds I have to assume that's what they want in the conversion. I made an update to my request.

Comment: How much more validation do you need?  You have a problem report and you have repeated the behavior.  The fix it to write your own parser.  Correct split is not enough.  Welcome to Regex.

Comment: Probably on the same level as the TextFieldParser. The input data could be almost anything as long as it adheres to the CSV format with any fields with embedded quotes will be enclosed with quotes. I guess that's where I am an not really knowing how to continue.

Comment: SO is not a code generation tool.  You need to start with a specific programming question.

Comment: Yes I understand, Im not here to ask someone to generate code for me. What Im asking for is options. RegEx is one but seems to have some pitfalls. Ive found two libraries that Im going to test. Ill post my results.